# Highchart set min on combo-duel-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Been looking and trying every thing I found and can think of.
I'm trying to set a minimum for the chart for the Y-axis (Time ms) & 100 max for the percentage on the x-axis and can't figure out where to put the

> {min: 0} // For Time

```
{max: 100} // for the percent x-axis
```

Some places it works but takes away some of the chart data or menu's

full code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Network Ping Results'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: [{
            //echo php dates for data
            categories: [<?php echo $categories;?>]
        }],
        // Primary yAxis Time ms
        yAxis: [{ 
            labels: {
                format: '{value} ms',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }

            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Time',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        },
        // Secondary yAxis 
        { 
            title: {
                text: 'Packet Loss',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} %',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Packet Loss',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            //Data echo for packet loss:
            data: [<?php echo $packet_loss;?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Average Time',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'spline',
            //Data echo for time:
            data: [<?php echo $avg_times;?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' ms'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show an image or provide a working chart with the steps to face problem ?

Comment: Could you attach content of your php variables, or data which you use?